# drop file into area - styleing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, plupload

There is a pluploader, it has a file drop zone and its id is `dropFilesHere`;

```
var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
        drop_element : "dropFilesHere", 
        /*...*/
    });
```

I would like to make some changes* (like gmail file attachment) on the drop zone if the user holds the file over it.

*For example:

```
.mouse_over{
    border-width:5px border-style:dashed #808080;
}
```

Sample:
[image: droping a file]

How can I do this?

---

```
uploader.bind('Init', function(up, params) {
    $('#filelist').html("<div>Current runtime: " + params.runtime + "</div>");
    if(params.runtime === 'html5') {
        $('#dropFilesHere').on({
            "dragenter": function(){
                $(this).addClass('mouse_over');
            },
            "dragleave drop": function(){
                $(this).removeClass('mouse_over');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided the initialized runtime is html5, you can try something like this :

```
// the runtime has been initialized :
var uploader = $(item).pluploadQueue();

if(uploader.runtime === 'html5') {
$('li.plupload_droptext').bind('dragenter', function() {
    $(this).css("border", "5px dashed #000000");
});

$('li.plupload_droptext').bind('dragleave', function() {
    $(this).css("border", "0px none");
});
}
```

tested on Chrome 18 and Firefox 11.
Hope this can help.

I realize another issue is then to disallow dropping outside of the drop-zone...

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for this! I have made some changes (using on, adding drop event, put this code to the init part of uploader), see my updated question.

Comment: wasn't sure for the ".on" (still haven't upgraded to jq1.7...)
Thx for the updated code :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using CSS `:hover` selector?

```
.dropFilesHere:hover {
    border-width:5px border-style:dashed #808080;
}
```

Also you can attach jQuery triggers for the client using `$('.dropFilesHere').mouseout()` and `$('.dropFilesHere').mouseenter()` or just the pure `$('.dropFilesHere').hover()`

It is always better to use CSS now a days anyway as it is more efficient than JS sometimes.

Comment: Hi! This works, but not that way I need. I would like this style to be apply if the user drags a FILE and goes with the cursor over the div area. See the picture!